# What is a less verbose way to check if multiple paths exist? C#

Tags: c#, .net, verbose

First time using asking a question on stackoverflow and I am also a beginner. I have written this code to check if multiple directories exist within my program. I need help making less verbose. It is very repetitive code that works but I feel like it is using too many words and if statements to do a simple task.

Here is the code:

```
            string destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string movedPath = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

            string destPath2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
            string movedPath2 = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

            string destPath3 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
            string movedPath3 = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

            string destPath4 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string movedPath4 = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

            string destPath5 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
            string movedPath5 = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

            string destPath6 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string movedPath6 = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";


            if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath))
            {

            }
            else
            {
              
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath2))
            {

            }
            else
            {
               
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath3))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath4))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath5))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath6))
            {

            }
            else
            {
               
            }
```

Comment: What do you want to do in  ```if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath))``` ,  ```if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath2))````,...? Do you want to implement different actions here?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with that information. Checking whether any or all paths exist is simple. Doing something different about each one makes it more complicated.

Comment: Probably best to move the generalized logic into a function. As a side point: use `Path.Combine` rather than `+ "\..."`

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I am here assuming that you actually wanted to alternate which `destPath` that is being referred to in your `movedPath*` values; i.e. that `string movedPath2 = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";` should rather be `string movedPath2 = destPath2 + @"\MyfolderTest";`, and so on.)

First, I'd identify *what actually changes* for each repeated code snippet. That may be easier to see if you visualize or edit the order of your logic from:

```csharp
string destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string movedPath = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

string destPath2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
string movedPath2 = destPath2 + @"\MyfolderTest";

// and so on

if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath)) { }
else { }

if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath2)) { }
else { }

// and so on
```

to

```csharp
string destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string movedPath = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";

if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath)) { }
else { }

string destPath2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
string movedPath2 = destPath2 + @"\MyfolderTest";

if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath2)) { }
else { }

// and so on...
```

You observe that each repeated part comprises a `destPath*` variable, a `movedPath*` variable and an `if/else` loop that considers the `movedPath*` variable.

You also observe that *what actually changes* is the input parameter for the `Environment.GetFolderPath( )` method; i.e. `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` and `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic`.

By collecting all the possible input parameters for the `Environment.GetFolderPath( )` method, e.g. in an array or a list, you can iterate over the input parameters in a `foreach` loop. Then, the `foreach` loop can contain your logic, and you will only need to define it once:

```csharp
string[] folderPaths = new[]
{
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic,
};

string destPath;
string movedPath;

foreach (var folderPath in folderPaths)
{
    destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(folderPath);
    movedPath = destPath + @"\MyfolderTest";
    
    if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath)) { }
    else { }
}
```

As a last improvement, I'd recommend you to move the `@"\MyfolderTest"` value outside the loop. It's better practice not to hard-code strings inside your logic. It may be defined as a constant in your class, or be a variable that is populated from user input.

The end result may look like this:

```csharp
string folderName = @"\MyfolderTest";

string[] folderPaths = new[]
{
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures,
    Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile
};

string destPath;
string movedPath;

foreach (var folderPath in folderPaths)
{
    destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(folderPath);
    movedPath = destPath + folderName;
    
    if (!Directory.Exists(movedPath))
    {
        // TODO
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```